# Pyspark error when I do an action on Dataframe which I created manually

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a python list of strings. I created a dataframe out of it with one column with this code:

`skills_df = spark.createDataFrame(temp, StringType())`

where, temp is the list of strings. 
This step was successfully executed.

When I try to do any action on `skills_df` like `skills_df.count()`, it gives me an error. It happens with this dataframe. But, not with a dataframe which I had created by importing csv file i.e. `csv_df = spark.read.csv('/user/turing/Profiles_final.csv', header=True)`. 
I ran this using `spark-submit`. While to debug, I ran the same code in `pyspark`, I got the same error. But, when I did a `csv_df.count()`, even after the error occurred, it ran fine.
Please help me with this error. Following is the stacktrace:

```
18/04/26 07:05:10 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Stage 14 contains a task of very large size (215 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
18/04/26 07:05:11 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 658, spark-w-1.c.amulya.internal, executor 2): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/conda/bin/python": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 33 more

18/04/26 07:05:11 ERROR org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 2 in stage 14.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
18/04/26 07:05:11 WARN org.apache.spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: No stages are running, but numRunningTasks != 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/turing/mi/sample_job.py", line 95, in <module>
    skills = processing_methods.get_skills(company, position, company_df)
  File "/home/turing/mi/sample_job.py", line 72, in get_skills
    return skills_df.groupBy('value').count().head(5)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 972, in head
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 476, in take
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 438, in collect
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o134.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 14.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 14.0 (TID 667, spark-w-1.c.amulya.internal, executor 2): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/conda/bin/python": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 33 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply$mcI$sp(Dataset.scala:2808)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2805)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2805)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2828)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:2805)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/conda/bin/python": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 33 more

18/04/26 07:05:11 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 656, spark-w-0.c.amulya.internal, executor 4): TaskKilled (stage cancelled)
18/04/26 07:05:11 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@3af4a719{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
18/04/26 07:05:11 WARN org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher: Message RemoteProcessDisconnected(10.138.0.6:39486) dropped. Could not find OutputCommitCoordinator.
```

The spark is running on a google cloud dataproc cluster. 
Thanks.

EDIT 1:

following is the temp variable with its values:

`temp = ['javascript', 'html', 'css', 'jquery', 'ajax', 'ruby on rails', 'agile', 'linux']`

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I have modified the answer to include the temp variable. I created it just by running that line directly. Please have a look. Yes, Error message isn't clear to me. Because, if it had been python path issue, it would not have been ran the csv_df.count() even after the error in the same pyspark session.

Comment: yes. It's the same error stacktrace which I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: The first line on the stacktrace has message:  WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Stage 14 contains a task of very large size (215 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB. 
Do you think if the size of the list is too large like 10k strings, this might cause the error I'm facing?

Comment: when you do `skills_df = spark.createDataFrame(temp, StringType())` you don't specify any filename and how come you are getting `Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory` ??

Comment: Spark can't run `/opt/conda/bin/python` on executors (on worker nodes). Are you using the conda init action in `dataproc-initialization-actions`? What's the full command you used to create the cluster? Also, try submitting the smoke test in that init action's folder to check that the install succeeded: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/conda/get-sys-exec.py.

Comment: @KarthikPalaniappan I created the cluster from the Web interface of cloud console. During the creation of the cluster, I hadn't put any initialization action. Though, after I SSHed to master for the first time, I had ran that conda init action. When I ran using the command `python get-sys-exec.py` or `\opt\conda\bin\python get-sys-exec.py`, I got this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'`. Do I need to install pyspark using pip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Init actions need to be run on *all* nodes of the cluster, not just the master. The driver started successfully because you had run the init action on the master, but then the job failed on executors because they did not have Conda installed.

In general, you should not run initialization actions manually. E.g. if you later add nodes to the cluster, you will need to run the script on the new nodes as well. However, if you specify initialization actions when creating a cluster, Dataproc will handle that for you.

You can specify init actions through the web console:

[image]

[image]

Note that if you want to specify metadata (flags) to the init actions, such as conda packages to install, you will need to use gcloud. The easiest way to do that is to start from "Equivalent command line" at the bottom of the create cluster page.

In general, I would suggest deleting and recreating your cluster if you want to want to add init actions or add flags. This is especially easy if your input data resides outside the cluster (e.g. Cloud Storage).